# Opening ports using iptables

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

I have tried opening port 5901 of my server using the following command

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I tested the port using https://www.infobyip.com/tcpportchecker.php

It says connection refused. I also wrote a script for testing the connection, which is also telling the same output.
That means the port is not accepting any connections.

What I need is to allow tcp connections to this port.
Suggest me a possible fix.

I am using Centos 6.9

Comment: Search on http://serverfault.com/, http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/. The server may be behind a firewall or NAT.

Comment: connection refused typically means the server is up, the port is not blocked, but there is no listener on the port. Do you have a process listening on that port? `netstat -a -t` can be used to check.

Comment: This was the issue.. Thank you..  ( Was not really an issue at all.. Silly mistake )

Answer (score 0):

The listening process was not running. Run the process and the issue is resolved.